# Edit Suite Bar Links in SharePoint 2019

Tags: branding, edit, spnavigationnode, powershell-script

I have tried all of the solutions provided for editing the Text in the Nav Suite Bar in **SharePoint 2019**.  I am trying to change the text from "SharePoint" to "Intranet" or the name of our company.  I tried the CSS solution and PowerShell scripts.
The PowerShell script works for everything except the SuiteNavBrandingText.  Running the script produces no change.
Is this something in SP 2019?  Are there any suggestions for changing the "SharePoint" and link?

Comment: take  a look on this. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/391ff522-0ff0-4d7c-b5a5-36d84b30decb/change-text-quotsharepointquot-in-mscorebrandingtext?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have the PowerShell solution and I have been able to change everything except the Name.  I found that the 2019 page uses a div class "o365cs-nav-brandingText" for the Name.  I used the Development Tool to find the element, and changing the Name here is successful.  I just don't know how to make the change using the PowerShell script. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Didn't work at my onPremise Farm.

Comment: The above solution did not work on On premise modern site.

Answer (score 3):

[Example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx)

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://webapp"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingText = "Intranet"
$webapp.Update()
```

*** This does not work for SP2019 ***